# Activity not found exception Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is the error in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.slehmann.volumetimechanger.MAINACTIVITY }
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slehmann.volumetimechanger"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.slehmann.volumetimechanger.APP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>
          <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".splash" > 
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my intent:

```
} finally {
    Intent openMenus = new Intent("com.slehmann.volumetimechanger.MAINACTIVITY");
    startActivity(openMenus);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
} finally { Intent openMenus = new Intent("com.slehmann.volumetimechanger.APP"); startActivity(openMenus); }
```

or

```
 } finally { Intent openMenus = new Intent(CLASSNAME.this, TARGETCLASSNAME.class); startActivity(openMenus); }
```

or change the `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.slehmann.volumetimechanger.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
      <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".splash" > 
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a silly mistake, your activity name is **MainActivity** and in your intent call you have declared it as **MAINACTIVITY** for that reason that happening. It would be like --

```
finally {
                Intent openMenus = new Intent("com.slehmann.volumetimechanger.MainActivity");
                startActivity(openMenus);
            }
```

Comment: Action *strings* have nothing to do with the Activity *classes* names that can handle them.

Answer (score 0):

your activity name is `MainActivity` into `manifest` and When call intent then use `MAINACTIVITY` for that reason that happening. Remember about the `uppercase` and `lowercase`.

and another thing:

Only One activity should be registered with the Category of Launcher.

```
<activity android:name=".FirstClassName"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Other Activities Should be Declare like this with no Extra Permissions.

```
<activity android:name=".SecondClassName"/>
```

So declare into manifest:

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

</activity>
```

Remove the

```
<intent-filter>
     //
      </intent-filter>
```

From the  manifest for the MainActivity declare.